# how to stop the animation effect in Jquery (the stop method)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new with Jquery and I'm trying to do an animation, but I can't figure out how to stop the animation.

I have 3 images that don't have equal heights or widths in 3 anchor tags, that are stacked in a div.

I made a script, when you mouseenter() an image the image's width should  grow width 20px, when you mouseleave() the width should get to the previews width.

I managed to do this, but when I go over the images with the mouse very fast the start growing and shrinking and the layout gets messy.

I found a few plugins that would do what I need but they all use images with equal widths and heights.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

here is a link with the code http://jsfiddle.net/ClaudiuTicu/9kTft/2/

```
 var original_w;
$('.getBigger').on('mouseenter', function () {
    original_w = $(this).find('img').width(); //add the width of thye image to the parent
    original_h = $(this).find('img').height(); //add the height to the parent

    if ($(this).find('img').is(':animated')) { }
    else {
        if ($(this).attr('style')) { } //has the style attribut
        else {
            $(this).css({
                'width': original_w,
                'height': original_h
            });
        } //dosen't have the style attribut
    }

    if ($(this).find('img').width() == original_w) {
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            'width': original_w + 20
        }).addClass('hovered');
    } //if the image width is equal with the parent's width
    else {

    }


}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    if ($(this).find('img').width() != original_w) {
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            'width': original_w
        }).removeClass('hovered');
    }
    console.log(original_w);
}); //end mouse leave
```

Comment: Check the docs; http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Your code seems not only got problem with animation but also got problem with the image size when you hover fast in and fast out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.stop(true,true)` before all instances of `.animate()` - it forces the animation to go its final state, and removes all queued animations.

Example:

```
$(this).find('img').stop(true,true).animate(...);
```